# How to eliminate left recursion in context-free grammar?

Tags: regex, parsing, context-free-grammar, recursive-descent

How would I eliminate the left recursion in this CFG?

```
<RE> -> <RE>'|'<CONCAT> | <CONCAT>
<CONCAT> -> <CONCAT><KLEEN> | <KLEEN>
<KLEEN> -> <KLEEN>'*' | <ELEM>
<ELEM> -> 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | '('<RE>')'
```

Comment: Assuming this is homework, make an effort first. Yourself. Even if it's not homework, show what has been tried and exactly what issue(s) are being encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the section on [Removing Left Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion#Removing_left_recursion) on Wikipedia.

Theres an description of exactly how to do it, following of;

Moore, Robert C. (May 2000). "Removing Left Recursion from Context-Free Grammars" . 6th Applied Natural Language Processing Conference: 249–255. http://aclweb.org/anthology-new/A/A00/A00-2033.pdf .